# How to ignore few characters in search and replace in vim editor

Tags: vim, replace

I want to do something like this in the vim editor:

> :%s/SETR P:LL../SETR P:LH../g

There are multiple lines which start with `SETR P:` in my file where I want to replace the second `L` with an `H` while the remaining two letters in that line will be the same as it was before.

Say if it was earlier  `SETR P:LLHC`
After replacing it would be `SETR P:LHHC`

Can I do it in one instruction with the vim editor?

Answer (score 2):

This is commonly done with *capture groups*. Capture the part of the source pattern that you want to re-include in the replacement via `\(...\)`. Then, in the replacement, you can refer to that part via `\1` (and following via `\2`, and so on):

```
:%s/SETR P:LL\(..\)/SETR P:LH\1/g
```

This is documented under `:help /\(`.

---

An alternative here would be to end the match after the `LL`, using `\ze` (match end). The rest of the pattern (`..`) is still checked, but it is not part of the match.

```
:%s/SETR P:LL\ze../SETR P:LH/g
```

---

By the way, your pattern will also happily match longer ends, e.g. `SETR P:LLHHHHHHHH`. If you need to limit the extension to two letters, use `..\>` (keyword boundary) or `..\A\@=` (non-alphabetic lookahead).

Comment: I have tried it on my file and it works. Thanks for the fruitful reply :)

Comment: Ah, glad I could help! Please accept the answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark. This way, the question is marked as closed, and you increase your chances of getting answers to future questions, as this shows that you care about the answers.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could just settle for:

```
:%s/SETR P:LL/SETR P:LH/
```

To exclude the preceding text from the match you can use the [`\@<=`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%3C%3D)  look-behind assertion or [`\zs`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Czs):

```
:%s/\(SETR P:L\)\@<=L/H/
:%s/SETR P:L\zsL/H/
```

Similarly, for excluding the subsequent text from the match [`\@=`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%3D) and [`\ze`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cze) can be used.

Comment: Thank you for such a helpful reply